# Get a "summary" of a class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to get a summary of a class in Objective-C?

Actually, this is a couple of classes in one file.

Things like private methods, public methods, private properties and ivars, public properties and iVars, imports etc...

Comment: Like `[NSObject description]` you mean?

Comment: @Droppy more like something that I can print out and read. Like a list of methods and dependencies and stuff...

Comment: @Droppy no, just for use to try and get my head around a class that is far too large to skim read. lol :D

Comment: And the Xcode Class Browser doesn't cut it?

Comment: [This](https://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/how-to-generate-beautiful-apple-style-documentation-in-xcode-5/) link may help. It explains how to document your classes and how to export that documentation

Comment: @Droppy Even on my 1080p monitor it is three pages long :(

Comment: Something like class-dump might be useful here: http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/

Comment: Nothing exists that I'm aware of which describes precisely what you're looking for. Consider writing a category on `NSObject` called `extensiveDescription` or something, that contains all the information you'd need.